# Javascript and jquery work with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

My html page cannot work in IE browser. If I turn F12 developer tools on, it starts to work. My page can work with chrome. I guess it is caused by jquery and javascript. Can anyone know how to make it work? Thanks

Comment: It could very well be bc you're using `console.log` somewhere, but nobody can say for sure if you don't show us some code. If your script is throwing an error in IE, you can use the dev-tools to see where in the script the code fails... remember: IE (<9 at least) doesn't support arary-access on string constants, nor does it pass the event object to the handler - even if you _correct_ for this, the event object doesn't support the `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation` methods, prototypes aren't as accessible either etc, etc... bottom line _show us some code_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE crashes your script if you're using console.log anywhere inside it. Developer tools adds the console functionality - therefor it works if you open it. Remove the console.log and it should start working just fine.

Chrome/Firefox support this by default, thats why it works there no problem.

Comment: Pretty sure this is only an issue in IE <= 8.

Comment: I wouldn't do this if you're logging a ton of stuff, but you can always wrap it in: try { console.log(/*whatever*/); } catch (e) {}

Comment: Just tested it, the issue is the same in IE9.

Comment: @roacher: Was it in "compatibility mode"?

Answer (score 0):

you're probably using console.log() in your code somewhere. In IE console object doesn't exist unless the dev tools window is active.